# Using foreach and nested array to insert rows in MySql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I've written the follow code to try and insert data into a table on the database. However it's just inserting letters. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$media_items = array( 
array (
   "media_name" => "Facebook",
   "link_url" => "http://www.facebook.com/insightdezign",
   "icon" => "facebook.png",
   "size" => "48",
   "order" => "0"
),
array (
   "media_name" => "Twitter",
   "link_url" => "http://www.twitter.com/insightdezign",
   "icon" => "twitter.png",
   "size" => "48",
   "order" => "1"
)
);

foreach ($media_items as $media_item) {
    if (is_array($media_item)){
        foreach ($media_item as $item) {
            $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $ffui_items, array( 'media_name' => $item['media_name'], 'link_url' => $item['link_url'], 'icon' => $item['icon'], 'size' => $item['size'], 'order' => $item['order'] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove this `foreach ($media_item as $item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your nested foreach loop, you will be looping over strings, not arrays. As a result of type juggling, the indexes will be evaluated to `0`. Since PHP also accepts `$foo['bar']` syntax on strings, it will just return the first letter.

You can simply remove the nested foreach loop and do it as follows:

```
foreach ($media_items as $media_item) 
{
    if (is_array($media_item))
    {
        $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $ffui_items, 
            array( 
            'media_name' => $media_item['media_name'], 
            'link_url' => $media_item['link_url'], 
            'icon' => $media_item['icon'], 
            'size' => $media_item['size'], 
            'order' => $media_item['order'] 
            ) ;
    }
}
```